# When Using Multiple ViewModels How To data-bind elements using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I currently have 2 viewmodels that I have combined. Now I want to data-bind this MasterViewModel to my elements in the page but not sure how.

Here is my HTML:

```
   <select data-bind="options: MasterViewModel.VMPR.ProjectName">
   </select>
   <select data-bind="options: MasterViewModel.VMTT.TaskTypeDetail">
   </select>
```

My ViewModels, and Binding Model:

```
 var ProjectDS = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.ProjectID = ko.observable(data.ProjectID);
        self.ProjectName = ko.observable(data.ProjectName);

    }

    var ProjectModel = function (Projects) {
        var self = this;
        self.Projects = ko.observableArray(Projects);

        $.ajax({
            url: "CreateTask.aspx/GetTaskProjects",
            // Current Page, Method  
            data: '{}',
            // parameter map as JSON  
            type: "POST",
            // data has to be POSTed  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // posting JSON content      
            dataType: "JSON",
            // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
            timeout: 10000,
            // AJAX timeout  
            success: function (Result) {
                var MappedProjects =
              $.map(Result.d,
       function (item) { return new ProjectDS(item); });
                self.Projects(MappedProjects);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }

        });
    };


    var TaskTypeDS = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.TaskTypeID = ko.observable(data.TaskTypeID);
        self.TaskTypeDetail = ko.observable(data.TaskTypeDetail);

    }

    var TaskTypeModel = function (TaskTypes) {
        var self = this;
        self.Projects = ko.observableArray(TaskTypes);

        $.ajax({
            url: "CreateTask.aspx/GetTaskTypes",
            // Current Page, Method  
            data: '{}',
            // parameter map as JSON  
            type: "POST",
            // data has to be POSTed  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // posting JSON content      
            dataType: "JSON",
            // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
            timeout: 10000,
            // AJAX timeout  
            success: function (Result) {
                var MappedTaskType =
              $.map(Result.d,
       function (item) { return new TaskTypeDS(item); });
                self.Projects(MappedTaskType);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }

        });
    };



    var MasterViewModel = {
            VMPR: new ProjectModel(),
            VMTT: new TaskTypeModel()
        }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel);
    })
```

And Finally here is the JSON I get in return:

```
{
"VMPR": {
    "Projects": [
        {
            "ProjectID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Dummy Project"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 3,
            "ProjectName": "Dummy Project2"
        }
    ]
},
"VMTT": {
    "Projects": [
        {
            "TaskTypeID": 1,
            "TaskTypeDetail": "Documentation"
        },
        {
            "TaskTypeID": 2,
            "TaskTypeDetail": "Development"
        },
        {
            "TaskTypeID": 3,
            "TaskTypeDetail": "Planning"
        },
        {
            "TaskTypeID": 4,
            "TaskTypeDetail": "Integration"
        },
        {
            "TaskTypeID": 5,
            "TaskTypeDetail": "Deployment"
        },
        {
            "TaskTypeID": 6,
            "TaskTypeDetail": "Testing"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to bind the correct property of your view model to each select, and then [set which property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) to use for the text and which to use as the value:

```
<select data-bind="options: VMPR.Projects, optionsText: 'ProjectName', optionsValue: 'ProjectID', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

<select data-bind="options: VMTT.Projects, optionsText: 'TaskTypeDetail', optionsValue: 'TaskTypeID', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

You also need to flatten your view model, so you don't have the two nested viewmodels:

```
var ProjectModel = function (Projects) {
    var self = this;
    self.Projects = ko.mapping.fromJS(Projects);
};


var TaskTypeModel = function (TaskTypes) {
    var self = this;
    self.Projects = ko.mapping.fromJS(TaskTypes);
}

$(function () {
var MasterViewModel = {
    VMPR: ko.mapping.fromJS(data.VMPR),
    VMTT: ko.mapping.fromJS(data.VMTT)
};
    ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel);
})
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SNbw7/1/)

To get this working with your two ajax calls:

```
var TaskTypeModel = function (TaskTypes) {
    var self = this;
    self.Projects = ko.observableArray(TaskTypes);

    $.ajax({
        url: "CreateTask.aspx/GetTaskTypes",
        // Current Page, Method  
        data: '{}',
        // parameter map as JSON  
        type: "POST",
        // data has to be POSTed  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // posting JSON content      
        dataType: "JSON",
        // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
        timeout: 10000,
        // AJAX timeout  
        success: function (Result) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(Result, self.Projects);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        }

    });
};
```

Comment: Again the scholar strikes!

Comment: @Paul, it looks like the objects do bind but no text gets displayed in my select. Any recommendations?

Comment: Try the updated code. I wasn't sure about the single quote marks around the optionsText value, but the example has that in. See if it works without those quote marks.

Comment: @Paul, it populates but for each text it shows [object] object]?

Comment: @G-Man See if the with binding helps here.

Comment: @Paul, this is the error I gt when I use 'with'; Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Projects is not defined;
Bindings value: options: Projects, optionsText: TaskTypeDetail, optionsValue: TaskTypeID, optionsCaption: 'Choose...

Comment: I'm just having a mess with a jsFiddle. I think it's an issue to how the view models are getting created.

Comment: Could you perhaps assist me with the viewmodel, the code for my viewmodel is oin my post?

Comment: Is it critical that you have nested view models? I've got it to work with VMPR and VMTT as properties on the MasterViewModel, using the knockout mapping plugin to process the data. http://jsfiddle.net/SNbw7/1/ I've got to go out now, but I'll be able to check back in a few hours.

Comment: @Paul, it is not critical that it needs to be nested. just need to access it and bind it to my select.

Comment: @Paul, I saw what you did in the fiddle with the JSON data but how will I go about doing so with my ajax post?

Comment: @PaulManzotti, when combining the Json data into 1 viewmodel. It does not return any value

Comment: @G-Man Is the data definitely being returned in the same format as in your question? As that's what I copied into the jsFiddle?